# How to add first 3-4 post tags on WordPress Post Title

Tags: posts, tags, get-posts, wp-title

Is there any theme function code that put the first 3-4 post tags on WordPress Post Title. Let's assume I am creating a new article for my site and I added the below tags for my post

My Post Title - `Wishing You a Very Happy Birthday`

My Post tags -  `Balloon, Birthday, Wishes, Gift, Celebration, Party`

I want to put the first 4 tags to my post title whenever I publish or save draft the post. My title should be like:

`Wishing You a Very Happy Birthday - Balloon, Birthday, Wishes, Gift`

I also want to add a custom text `Greeting` at the end of the post title.

Comment: You mean the tags with the lowest term id? There is no other order beside that.

Comment: Does it add all tags of the post? if you have 20 for example, will it add all of them?. Also this can cause duplication, because every time you edit/update the post it will append those tags again. Maybe it would be better to hook into `the_title` and append the tags there?

Comment: @fuxia Please find the image reference. https://gcdn.pbrd.co/images/TQBampfOOxfZ.png?o=1

Comment: @Buttered_Toast No, I want to put only first 4 tags. I have unique tags on every post title.

Comment: So … the first in alphabetical order?

Comment: @fuxia I managed to get the tags displayed on first come first served basis with the help from this thread (https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/174453/order-tags-but-not-alphabetically), as I am using a Image tagging API plugin which adds tags automatically.